# SQLAlchemy scoped_session update on thread wont commit

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I'm a total noob to SQLAlchemy here, but I'm having an issue updating an object from a threaded scoped_session. I'm planning to run several threads, all of which, will be updating different rows in the database, each with their own scoped_session. But I can't seem to get the scoped sessions to commit and actually update the .db file.

Below is the minimal code that recreates my issue:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from threading import Thread

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
session1 = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(iterable, **kwargs)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session1.add(Order({'name':'bill'}))
session1.commit()

orders = session1.query(Order).all()
print(orders[0].name)

def funct():
    session2 = Session()
    orders[0].name = "ted"
    session2.commit()
    Session.remove()
    print(orders[0].name)

t1 = Thread(target=funct)
t1.start()
```

the output from this (as expected) is:

```
bill
ted
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

But after running this, the .db file still only has one row with "bill"...  I don't understand why it is not being updated to "ted"...  I've spent some time reading thru the SQLAlchemy docs multiple times, but like I mentioned, I'm a total noob and a lot of it is over my head.
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

-Brandon

Comment: `orders` is from `session1`, but `session1` is never committed.  Probably you want to run a query in `session2` that gets the order(s) that you want, and then does the update.  Or look at the session documentation for detaching and merging objects and sessions

Comment: Yep, just to add to @snakecharmerb 's response, here's [the relevant docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe):

> ...not just the Session object itself, but also all objects that are associated with that Session, must be kept within the scope of a single concurrent thread.

See also [`Session.merge()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge)

Comment: That was it!!  thank you both for your help!!